# List_rount doesn't work in Django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

According to this link http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/

```
class UserViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    ...

    @detail_route(methods=['post'], permission_classes=[IsAdminOrIsSelf])
    def set_password(self, request, pk=None):
```

The following URL pattern would additionally be generated:

- URL pattern: `^users/{pk}/set_password/$` Name: 'user-set-password'

And here is my code:
[image]

I want to generate `^calendars/{pk}/events/$` URL pattern. But it generated `^calendars/events/{pk}/$` according to below error page
[image]

So where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the wrong decorator in your code. You want `@detail_route`, not `@list_route`. `@list_route` does not accept a pk and therefore generates `/calendars/events/`

Your method should be decorated like this:

```
@detail_route(methods=['get'])
def events(self, request, pk=None):
    ...
```

Comment: I want to get event list through `^calendars/{pk}/events/$` not just a event. If @list_route does not accept a pk, how to implement this URL pattern?

Comment: `@detail_route` accepts a pk and generates the url you desire. I have added a code example.

Comment: It works, but still confused since I want a list but the detail of an item.

Comment: The list_route and detail_route only differentiate in the type of url that the router will generate for you. A deeper explanation can be found here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot. One more question, can I generate `^calendars/{calendar_pk}/events/{event_pk}/$` pattern with detail_route or list_route? I don't find related topic on official site.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. If you require nesting resources that deeply you will have to use a CustomRouter. Though, my experience with api design is to keep `/events/{event_pk}/` as it's own separate resource and not nest it.

Comment: This package is referenced by the documentation for nested routers: https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers